# Is there any way to make two GET query parameters point to two different routes (handler functions) in Golang or GIN?

Tags: go, go-gin

I am trying to do the following:

> /car?color= -> first route (endpoint) and first handler function
>
> /car?brand= -> second route (endpoint) and second handler function
>
> /car?type= -> third route (endpoint) and third handler function
>
> ...

I tried the following in GIN:

```
server.GET("/car?color=", carColorHandlerFunction)
server.GET("/car?brand=", carBrandHandlerFunction)
server.GET("/car?type=", carTypeHandlerFunction)
```

Also tried:

```
server.GET("/car?color=:carColor", carColorHandlerFunction)
server.GET("/car?brand=:carBrand", carBrandHandlerFunction)
server.GET("/car?type=:carType", carTypeHandlerFunction)
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. It does not recognize these routes.

Is there a way to make it work and how to make it with a GIN or with "basic" GO?

Comment: does it have to be done with query parameters?  I know you could do it with different URLs (i.e. `/car/color/{colour}`)

Comment: @blurfus Yes, I need it with query parameters.

Comment: as far as I know, there is no way to do it based on query parameters

Comment: Write a handler for /car that dispatches to other handlers using the query parameters.

Comment: @CeriseLimón If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that I write one function handler for /car and then inside that handler create if-else-if statements that, depending on the query parameters, will call the appropriate functions?

Comment: @Filip Yes. A switch or table driven approach may also be appropriate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make it work and how to make it with a GIN

No.

> or with "basic" GO?

No.